# Accessing heading,pitch and fov streetview values from delphi

Tags: delphi, gmlib

Im implementing a Delphi based tool that get long and lat values from an addresses database.
I want to be able to get the streetview values that google is returning.
I can see a streetview class is defined but only with visible propertly.
Is there any way to Access heading,pitch and fov values after querying google with full address data(data like https://support.google.com/mapcontentpartners/answer/160409?hl=en)?

EDITED---
Ok, will explain a bit more the question...
If we find 'Gran Via 12,28013 Madrid' at google maps we can see the map with a thumb containing the streetview. Using decoding service i can obtaing long/lat values, in this case 40.4196892,-3.6989026.

Thats nice but 'Gran Via 13,28013 Madrid' can have the same long,lat geocoding values but other heading,pitch,fov ones...

So... anyway to obtain that values using any api? 
I can reproduce the browser search/ look the code of that thumbnail button and parse heading from it...

```
<div class="imagery-entry-point-image" style='width: 374px; height: 75px; background-image: url("//geo0.ggpht.com/cbk?cb_client=maps_sv.tactile&amp;output=thumbnail&amp;thumb=2&amp;it=1,2,4,5,11&amp;w=374&amp;h=75&amp;yaw=3&amp;pitch=0&amp;ll=40.419542,-3.698914");' jsl="$x 2;" jstid="405"></div>
```

... but it seems to appear so nasty... :p

Comment: I think I don't understand you, but... if you geocode this address, you can get all this information

Comment: Yeah! My explanation really sucks... i have a set of addresses and need to get complete (heading,fov,pitch rather than long/lat) from google response... :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You say you want to get the "values that Google is returning." Where do you see Google returning such values? If you can see them, what problem are you facing that prevents you from getting them? Please [edit] your question to provide more information about what you have and what you want.

Comment: Here's an open-source library for Google maps in Delphi. Does it help? http://www.cadetill.com/gmlib_en/

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess that this is what you are looking for. https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search

There are many ways to search Google maps data including full address, geolocation, and even by cellular data https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/

Due to lack of info, my best advice has to be to take some time to look around the API and decide how to best search your request.